# phpMyAdmin versus mysql_fetch_array - why can't I get GROUP BY to work?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple table called "board" that has a column called "sid" - that is just integers. Many of these are duplicates. I want to know only distinct values in this column, so I do this:

```
SELECT sid FROM board GROUP BY sid
```

When I run this query directly in phpMyAdmin, I get the set I was expecting. No problem. However, this bit of code returns every row in the entire table, without exception:

```
$sql = "SELECT sid FROM board GROUP BY sid";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);  
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
  echo $row["sid"] . "<br />";  
}
```

Does anyone know why? FYI I've tried every combination of DISTINCT and GROUP BY I could think of, but no matter what I do, I can't get a distinct set to echo out.

Comment: I hate to ask this, but are you selecting the right database?

Comment: I am not getting an error, I am getting a resultset that has every value, including duplicates. So yes, I am connecting to the right database, and yes, I'm getting a result - but not the right result, and not the result I get when I run the same query on the same database in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: `I am not getting an error`. But you should. `$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);` Always run your query this way.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like very strange behavior, but why don't you try this:

```
select distinct sid from board
```

Answer (score 0):

ACK. PEBKAC, sorry. Thanks for all the help. I didn't realize I had it nested in another loop and so the distinct resultset was actually echoing out multiple times.